# Something went wrong CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io

Tags: ethereum, alchemy

> Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node
> https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2
> at Object.ConnectionError (D:\QaptaInc-BLCH-V4\backend\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:66:23)
> at Object.InvalidConnection (D:\QaptaInc-BLCH-V4\backend\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:36:21)
> at HttpProvider.failed (D:\QaptaInc-BLCH-V4\backend\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib\index.js:136:25)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

When I'm traying to connect Ethereum rinkeby test network using alchemy API that time I'm getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this problem come from your local computer and you need to check access of the computer. Means some time you don't have access to your computer.